# How to isolate feature states when a feature can be opened in multiple tabs (at the application level), using ngrx?

Tags: angular, tabs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have to build an application using ngrx (requirement) with the following requirements:

- Multiple features, let's call them A, B and C.
- Tabs at the application level. A tab contains a feature and there are not limits on the number of tabs that can be opened.
- A feature can be opened in as many tabs as the user wants.
- A tab state must be isolated from other tabs, even if it contains the same feature.

The last point is the one were I'm stuck and I'm seriously losing sleep over this one and I'd like to get my life back. Has anyone any experience on how to do such a thing?

What I've done so far is build a sample application. After many days messing around with it I've got a solution working, but I feel like this would be pretty terrible to maintain. The solution I have is to:

- A feature that will be contained in a tab must have a state (e.g `FeatureAState`)
- This state will be stored inside a states map for this feature (e.g `FeatureAStates`), with the key being the id of the tab this states belongs to.
- When a tab navigation is done, I have to listen to this action in all the features to update their state to be aware of the current tab.
- We then use selector to get the feature state for the current active tab.

But the issues I have with the solution is that:

1) Every feature has to be aware of the fact that they are in tabs and I have to duplicate the selectedTabId in every feature (and do not forget to update it everytime the user navigates tabs). 
2) All the subfeatures must be wrapped in a `states: {[tabIdOfThisState: string]: SubFeatureState}`, which makes accessing properties painful.

How could I improve this solution?

Below you can find how the code looks like.

`tabs.actions.ts`:

```
// Tab is an interface with an id, a matching url and a label.
export const addNewTab = createAction('[Tabs] Add New Tab', props<{ tab: Tab}>());
export const navigateToTab = createAction('[Tabs] Navigate To Tab', props<{ tab: Tab }>());
export const closeTab =  = createAction('[Tabs] Close Tab', props<{ tab: Tab }>());
export const all = union({ addNewTab, navigateToTab });
export type TabsActionsUnion = typeof all;
```

`tabs.reducer.ts`:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Tab> { 
  selectedTabId: string;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Tab> = createEntityAdapter<Tab>({
  selectId: (tab: Tab) => tab.linkOrId,
});

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({ selectedTabId: undefined });

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: TabsActionsUnion) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case addNewTab.type: {
      return adapter.addOne(action.tab, state);
    }
    case navigateToTab.type: {
      return { ...state, selectedTabId: action.tab.id };
    }
    case closeTab.type: {
      // (todo): should handle the case where the tab being removed is the selected one
      return adapter.removeOne(action.tab.id, state);
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const getSelectedTabId = (state: State) => state.selectedTabId;
```

Then I have my feature A. My feature A handles multiple subfeatures, and in my sample application I've got one called `Counter`. Here is what the code looks like:

`counter.actions.ts`:

```
export const increaseCounter = createAction('[Counter] Increase Counter', props<{ tabId }>());
export const decreaseCounter = createAction('[Counter] Decrease Counter');
const all = union({ initializeCounter, increaseCounter, decreaseCounter });
export type CounterActions = typeof all;
```

`counter.reducer.ts`:

```
export interface CounterState {
  value: number; 
}

// this is the list of the different states, one per tab where the counter feature is used... 
export interface CounterStates {
  states: { [id: string]: CounterState };
  activeTabId: string; // this is the selected tab id, this is always the same one as the selectedTabId in the Tabs feature 
}

const initialStates = { states: {}, activeTabId: undefined };

const initialState = { value: 0 };

export function reducer(state: CounterStates = initialStates, action: CounterActions | TabsActionsUnion) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // when we add a new tab we need to initialize a new counter state for this tab. 
    // this also means that we cannot lazy load the store, because otherwise 
    // this reducer would not be initialized on the first addNewTab
    case addNewTab.type: {
      return {
        ...state,
        states: { ...state.states, [action.tab.id]: initialState },
        activeTabId: action.tab.id
      };
    }
    // we have to duplicate the activeTabId here because the reducer cannot access the
    // state of another feature...
    case navigateToTab.type: {
      return {
        ...state,
        activeTabId: action.tab.id
      };
    }
    // updating the value is painful because we need to make sure we modify only the right counter state...
    case increaseCounter.type: {
      return {
        ...state,
        states: {
          ...state.states,
          [action.tabId]: { ...state.states[action.tabId], value: state.states[action.tabId].value + 1 }
        }
      };
    }
    case decreaseCounter.type: {
      return {
        ...state,
        states: {
          ...state.states,
          [state.activeTabId]: { ...state.states[state.activeTabId], value: state.states[state.activeTabId].value - 1 }
        }
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

// selectors are ok to work with, this one I'm happy with
export const getValue = (state: CounterStates) => state.states[state.activeTabId].value;
```

and the reducer for the whole feature where `Counter` is used:

`index.ts`:

```
export interface FeatureAState {
  counter: fromCounter.CounterStates;
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  featureA: FeatureAState;
}

export const reducers = combineReducers({ counter: fromCounter.reducer });

export const getFeatureAStateState = createFeatureSelector<State, FeatureAStateState>('featureAState');

export const getFeatureAStateCounterState = createSelector(
  getFeatureAStateState,
  state => state.counter
);

export const getCounterValue = createSelector(
  getFeatureAStateState,
  fromCounter.getValue
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're using "the" correct solution. You will have to maintain the state for each tab and this can only be done by keeping a ref to its id, this is what you're doing.

I believe having a selector for the active tab id (via the url) is a clean solution